# Android Lockdown without a custom ROM?

Tags: android

I'm attempting to lock down an android tablet for kiosk-like functionality and have explored the existing application options for doing so, but have not found anything that meets my needs. Specifically, the tablet needs to be able to operate without a password in "normal" mode, locking the user out of any functionality other than that provided by the approved app (or apps); however, the tablet must not allow the user to bypass the kiosk functionality (for example, by entering "safe mode") without a password. The apps that I've used so far get around the "safe mode" problem by forcing you to provide a screen lock password, but this means the user has to supply a password each time the tablet is locked, which won't work for my use case (wherein users will take their tablets home and won't keep them on constantly).

My suspicion is that the functionality that I'm seeking can't be achieved at the application level and will require a custom ROM, but I thought I'd poll this group before embarking down that path.

Answer (score 2):

> The apps that I've used so far get around the "safe mode" problem by forcing you to provide a screen lock password

It is not possible to "get around the safe mode problem" except by modifying the firmware. Or, if it is, that means "safe mode" is itself broken. Whatever app has this "screen lock password" will not be running in safe mode, assuming that app is not part of the firmware.

> My suspicion is that the functionality that I'm seeking can't be achieved at the application level and will require a custom ROM

Technically, in principle, you could root the device, make some changes (e.g., remove the stock home screen APK and add in yours), and then un-root the device. I'm no expert on rooting, but I am under the impression that root is reversible in some, but perhaps not all, cases. This may allow for more "tactical" modification of the device environment without a full-on ROM mod.

That being said, bear in mind that if the device you are using *can* be rooted, it's possible that the rooting recipe could be executed by the user. That depends a bit on the recipe. Those that require you to have `adb` access, for example, can be blocked by not allowing USB debugging to be turned on. Those that simply require a magic file on external storage and a reboot, though, may be impossible to stop.